# Setting value in DB through EF because it is not in our models

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two classes Note and User and my Users have Notes. In my User class the connection is through List of Notes but in my DB is through UserID column in the Notes table so when I am adding Notes in my DbSet the UserID value is always null. How can I make the UserId to get the Id of the User when adding through DbSet.

```
public class Note
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public Note(string title, string text)
        {
            Title = title;
            Text = text;
        }
```

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    public User(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        Notes = new List<Note>();
    }
}
```

```
        public void AddNote(Note currentNote)
        {
            currentUser.Notes.Add(currentNote);
            DBContext.Notes.Add(currentNote);
            DBContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: The relationship between the two entities is a one-to-many as I understand; and it can be specified at either end and ef conventions will pick it up. What is not clear in your question is what you mean by _'when adding through DbSet'_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While EF can automatically work out relationships, it's generally a good idea to understand how to map them out explicitly so that you can handle situations where it hasn't got it quite right. This can be done via the OnModelCreating override on your DbContext, or by using `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` classes that are loaded by the DbContext.

For instance with the OnModelCreating: (assuming a Note's User is required, but a note has no User reference)

```
// EF 6 
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Notes)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("UserId"));
// EF Core
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Notes)
    .WithOne()
    .IsRequired()
    .HasForeignKey("UserId");
```

What these do is set up the relationship to use the UserId on the Notes table without needing to declare a UserId or User reference on the Notes entity.

From your example it's not clear where "currentUser" comes from when you call AddNote. When the relationship is set up correctly, EF will assign all required FKs automatically. The caveat being that you need to ensure that the entities were loaded from the same DbContext.  One potential issue I see is the scoping for your DbContext variable. Contexts should be short-lived, so things like static or even private member variables should be avoided, as you want to ensure that contexts are disposed when they aren't needed.  To be safe, the user should be pulled from the same DbContext you want to save the Note to, and you should avoid passing entities around outside of the scope of their DbContext. Pass DTOs or ViewModels (POCO non-entity classes)  or the relevant data, but load/create entities within the scope of a context and don't let them leave it.

```
    public void AddNote(NoteViewModel currentNote)
    {
        using(var context = new MyDBContext())
        {
            var currentUser = context.Users.Single(x => x.UserId = currentUserId);
            var note = new Note
            {
                Text = currentNote.Text,
                // ... other stuff.
            };
            currentUser.Notes.Add(currentNote);
             context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: currentUser comes from my view and after the user has logged I am using only this User so I have this property in my NoteController class. Thank you for the answer I will try this.